# Why is if $G$ and $H$ are disjoint,then $H \subset F $

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Question: Let $(\Omega,F,P)$be a probability space and consider events $F, G$, and $H$ for which $P(F) > P(G) > P(H) > 0$. Events $F$ and $G$ form a partition of $\Omega$, and events F and H are independent. Can events G and H be disjoint?

I can't understand the solution that teacher gave,here are the part of solution

$1$.$F$ & $G $ are partion of $\Omega$,that is ,$P(F \cup G)=P(F)+P(G)$

$2$.$F$ & $H $ are independent,that is,$P(F \cap H)=P(F)P(H)$

$3$.if $G$ and $H$ are disjoint,then $H \subset F $

I can't understand the 3.,can anyone explain it or take an example to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ and $H$ are disjoint, since $F=G^c$ from 1, (complement of $G$, up to a set of probability zero) then $H$ is forced to be a subset of the complement, since it has nonzero probability.

Comment: but why is there no possible that $G$ is a subset of $F$,then $F$ is disjoint to $H$? Although i  only know  F & H are independent ,it doesn't mean that F and H are disjoint,but it doesn't mean that F and H are joint either

Comment: is it because that $P(F)>P(G)>P(H)$,so $H$ must be a subset of $F$ ?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: F& G are partion of Ω,does this mean there is only two subset in this  Ω sample space?